# Python: How to change data type and override a variable from imported module

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two python programs in same folder named **main.py** and **tk_version.py**
I am importing main.py in tk_version.py
I have a variable in main.py which has default value lets say 'xyz'
Now in tk_version.py I am taking the value for the variable from user using Tkinter GUI.

So what I want is when main.py is executed the constant value must be taken and when tk_version.py is executed the value given by user override the default value.

Example:

**main.py**

```
var="default"
def show():
    print(var)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   show()
```

**tk_version.py**

```
from tkinter import *

import main

Main = Tk()

var= StringVar()
def e1chk():
    global var
    var = e1.get()
    main.show()
    return  


e1=Entry(Main,textvariable=var,width=50)

e1.grid(row=0,column=5,sticky=NSEW)

b1=Button(Main,text="Save",command=e1chk)
b1.grid(row=0,column=8,sticky=NSEW) 
Main.mainloop()
```

**OUTPUT for main.py**

```
>>> 
=============== RESTART: C:/Users/Gupta Niwas/Desktop/main.py ===============
default
>>>
```

**OUTPUT for tk_version.py** (I have entered "abc" in Entry box)

```
>>> 
============ RESTART: C:/Users/Gupta Niwas/Desktop/tk_version.py ============
default
>>>
```

**I want variable to be StringVar to control the entry box values.**

Comment: The `var` in tk_version.py is entirely unrelated to the `var` in main.py - `global` in Python means "global to this module", not "global everywhere".  After having done `import main`, `main.var` will refer to its variable.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't call show with an argument (even if just in one of the two cases, and the other uses a default)?

Comment: @jedwards  can't pass parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `main.` before your variable name.

**`tk_version.py`**

```
from tkinter import *

import main

Main = Tk()

main.var = StringVar()


def e1chk():
    main.var = e1.get()
    main.show()
    return


e1 = Entry(Main, textvariable=main.var, width=50)

e1.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky=NSEW)

b1 = Button(Main, text="Save", command=e1chk)
b1.grid(row=0, column=8, sticky=NSEW)
Main.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

```
abc
>>>
```

Comment: I want variable to be StringVar to control the entry box values.